# Can't hook up to external topic in KSql

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-platform, ksqldb

I'm very new to Confluent KSql but not new to Kafka.  I have existing topics that exist in Kafka as Avro serialized data.  I have the Confluent schema-registry up and running and configure KSql to point to the registry.

When I try to create a table baseed upon one of my topics KSql complains that it can't find the stream.  When I try to create a stream in KSql that simply streams my topic within KSql there appears to be no way to point to my Avro serialized topic which has a reference in the registry.

Does anyone know how to attack these two problems?  Is the way I want to use KSql not appropriate to what it can do?

**UPDATE**

Here's some more details

```
ksql> show topics;

 Kafka Topic                                                                                 | Registered | Partitions | Partition Replicas | Consumers | Consumer Groups
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 COM_FINDOLOGY_MODEL_REPORTING_OUTGOINGFEEDADVERTISERSEARCHDATA                              | false      | 2          | 2                  | 0         | 0
 COM_FINDOLOGY_MODEL_TRAFFIC_CPATRACKINGCALLBACK                                             | false      | 2          | 2                  | 0         | 0
 COM_FINDOLOGY_MODEL_TRAFFIC_ENTRYPOINTCLICK                                                 | true       | 10         | 3                  | 0         | 0
```

KSql config

```
#bootstrap.servers=localhost:9092
bootstrap.servers=host1:9092,host2:9092,host3:9092,host4:9092,host5:9092

#listeners=http://localhost:8088
listeners=http://localhost:59093

ksql.server.ui.enabled=true

ksql.schema.registry.url=http://host1:59092
```

Registry config

```
# The host name advertised in ZooKeeper. Make sure to set this if running Schema Registry with multiple nodes.
host.name: x.x.x.x
listeners=http://0.0.0.0:59092

# Zookeeper connection string for the Zookeeper cluster used by your Kafka cluster
# (see zookeeper docs for details).
# This is a comma separated host:port pairs, each corresponding to a zk
# server. e.g. "127.0.0.1:3000,127.0.0.1:3001,127.0.0.1:3002".
#kafkastore.connection.url=localhost:2181

# Alternatively, Schema Registry can now operate without Zookeeper, handling all coordination via
# Kafka brokers. Use this setting to specify the bootstrap servers for your Kafka cluster and it
# will be used both for selecting the master schema registry instance and for storing the data for
# registered schemas.
# (Note that you cannot mix the two modes; use this mode only on new deployments or by shutting down
# all instances, switching to the new configuration, and then starting the schema registry
# instances again.)
kafkastore.bootstrap.servers=PLAINTEXT://host1:9092,PLAINTEXT://host2:9092,PLAINTEXT://host3:9092,PLAINTEXT://host4:9092,PLAINTEXT://host5:9092

# The name of the topic to store schemas in
kafkastore.topic=_schemas

# If true, API requests that fail will include extra debugging information, including stack traces
debug=false
```

Attempting to solve the problem by declaring an external topic

```
ksql> register  topic xxx with (value_format='avro', kafka_topic='COM_FINDOLOGY_MODEL_REPORTING_OUTGOINGFEEDADVERTISERSEARCHDATA');
You need to provide avro schema file path for topics in avro format.
```

Comment: Can you show your query statements? And the errors?

Comment: I've tried various things so apologies for flooding you with stuff

Comment: ksql> register topic COM_FINDOLOGY_MODEL_REPORTING_OUTGOINGFEEDADVERTISERSEARCHDATA with (value_format='avro', kafka_topic='COM_FINDOLOGY_MODEL_REPORTING_OUTGOINGFEEDADVERTISERSEARCHDATA');
You need to provide avro schema file path for topics in avro format.

Comment: explain CREATE TABLE possible_fraud   AS SELECT clientIp, count(*)  from  COM_FINDOLOGY_MODEL_TRAFFIC_ENTRYPOINTCLICK               WINDOW TUMBLING (SIZE 5 SECONDS) GROUP BY clientIp  HAVING count(*) > 3;

COM_FINDOLOGY_MODEL_TRAFFIC_ENTRYPOINTCLICK does not exist.

Comment: ksql> select * from COM_FINDOLOGY_MODEL_TRAFFIC_ENTRYPOINTCLICK limit 3;
COM_FINDOLOGY_MODEL_TRAFFIC_ENTRYPOINTCLICK does not exist.

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question and format those statements? And you need to `REGISTER STREAM`, no? Not `REGISTER TOPIC`? For *You need to provide avro schema file path for topics in avro format*, sounds like you didn't configure the registry correctly

Comment: does `show topics;` work?

Answer (score 0):

`REGISTER TOPIC` is deprecated syntax. You should use `CREATE STREAM` (or `CREATE TABLE`, depending on your data access requirements).

So your statement would look something like this:

```
CREATE STREAM MY_STREAM_1 \
  WITH (VALUE_FORMAT='AVRO', \
  KAFKA_TOPIC='COM_FINDOLOGY_MODEL_REPORTING_OUTGOINGFEEDADVERTISERSEARCHDATA');
```

Note that I've used `\` to break the lines for readability; you don't have to do this.

Comment: So I tried your syntax and it did not work, _but_ I think what you wrote is correct.  I think the real issue is that the schema was created by **reflection** in Avro and it contains valid Avro definitions some of which do not correspond to anything in KSql.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue I had after changing what information I used from the Kafka topic, as opposed to using the whole topic contents.  The topic contains Avro encoded data (ok) created by using `ReflectionData`.  `KSql` has problems dealing with non-standard items in the stream but handles ReflectionData items as long as there is a corresponding KSql data type.  I resolved this by creating a new stream in KSql that only selected out the items I needed that are also compatible with KSql.  When that was done I could process what I needed from the larger stream.

*Comment* I see it as somewhat of a deficiency in KSql that you have to create new *actual* intermediary topic(s) in `Kafka` to process the data.  I think a better solution is to treat the intermediary stream as a `View` into the actual stream.  The need for intermediary topics to hold accumulations and processed items before resolving it as a KTable I understand.